# Touchscreen Pi GPIO Connection

Tags: gpio, hardware, touchscreen, pitft

I'm working on David Hunt's Touchscreen Pi Timelapse Controller (https://learn.adafruit.com/touchscreen-pi-timelapse-controller/overview) and have encountered some difficulty in the the hardware section of the instructions. I have a Raspberry Pi B+.

He specifies to connect to GPIO17, but this is being used by the PiTFT Touchscreen, which uses pins 1-26. I don't see another 3.3V power source that is not covered by the touchscreen. Is there a way to connect to GPIO17 with the Touchscreen on, or a way to get the power from another pin?

I'm really new to RasPi, so would appreciate some advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3V3 rail is only brought out on pins 1 and 17.

Your only choices appear to be

- an external 3V3 power supply (but then you'd have the same problem connecting the grounds)
- to carefully splice one of the 3V3 wires
- to carefully solder an insulated wire to pins 1 or 17 on the underside of the board

---

EDITED TO ADD

There is another option

- If the device needs only a little current at 3V3 (say 10 mA) use any
  accessible gpio and set it high.

Comment: Thank you- I'll try either option 3 or 4 and see how things go.